# Is the lmdb-devel package necessary for installing the cfengine on RHEL v.7 via an RPM .spec file?

Tags: rpm, packages, rhel7, specfile

I have a problem when I try to build from my spec file.  I run this:

```
rpmbuild -ba newpackage.spec
```

I see a great deal of output.  It ends with these lines:

```
configure: error: Cannot find Lightning MDB
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dKgUSh (%build)

RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dKgUSh (%build)
```

I tried to install lmdb-devel package to address the "Cannot find Lightning MDB."  There were many dependency packages.  I am using RHEL 7.  I couldn't even find where to download all the dependencies.  What should I do?  I'm concerned that installing the lmdb-devel won't even help me anyway.

Here is what my newpackage.spec file looks like:

```
Name:  cfengine
Version: 1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:  First time

License:        GNU
#URL:
Source0: http://s3.amazonaws.com/cfengine.package-repos/tarballs/cfengine-3.6.5.tar.gz

BuildRequires: gettext
# Requires:

%description
This is a test.

%prep
%setup -n cfengine-3.6.5


%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%make_install


%files
%doc


%changelog
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use standard systemd-compatible RPM package from CFEngine site?

http://s3.amazonaws.com/cfengine.package-repos/community_binaries/cfengine-community-3.6.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Yes, I want to use a spec file for future customization.  Right now this is a proof of concept.